# Blueimp Jquery File Upload json error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, upload

I am using jQuery File Upload Plugin for a personal website.
I have tried to add one additional column named "status" in the database table.

I have modified the function "protected function handle_file_upload(xxx,xxx...)".
as following

```
if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`,`status`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description,
                 '0'
            );
```

But it shows the error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character". What's wrong with the code?
Please advice.